# positioning background-image (multi image grid) with css

Tags: css, position, background-image

I have a 26x104 px image (so vertical oriented) containing 4 logo's, each a 26x26 px.

I want to use those 4 logo's as background for 4 hyperlinks.
So I have this:

HTML (this is the sequence I want)

```
<div class="rightfloat">
    <a class="facebook"></a>
    <a class="linkedin"></a>
    <a class="twitter"></a>
    <a class="mail"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.facebook, .linkedin, .twitter, .mail {
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-image: url('style/socialmedia.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.facebook {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.linkedin {
    background-position: 0px -26px;
}
.twitter {
    background-position: 0px -52px;
}
.mail {
    background-position: 0px -78px;
}
```

For some reason only the first one appears but with other testing it also happend that the last icon appeared at the second link...so appearantely I don't get the logics behind it.

I looked for some example/tutorial but I can't find one.
Can someone give me a hand?

SOLUTION: I have put the coördinates in negative values and it worked...

Comment: remove `background-repeat` attr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the values as negative:

[Working demo](http://jqversion.com/#!/8G3s3LO)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I have put the coördinates in negative values and it worked...